# What could cause a binding to no update the source

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox defined like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" 
    Text="{Binding Text}"
    IsEditable="True"
    TextSearch.TextPath="Label"
    DisplayMemberPath="Label" />
```

Here is my view Model:

```
public class ComboBoxViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _selectedCode;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> Choices { get; }

    public ComboBoxItem Value
    {
        get { return this.Choices.FirstOrDefault(choice => choice.Code == _selectedCode); }
        set
        {
            this.SetCode(value?.Code)
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.Value?.Label ?? _selectedCode; }
        set
        {
            // Only set the code if no pre-defined code can be selected
            if (this.Value == null)
            {
                this.SetCode(value)
            }
        }
    }

    public ComboBoxViewModel()
    {
        this.Choices = [..];
    }

    public bool SetCode(string code)
    {
        if (_selectedCode != code)
        {
            _selectedCode = code;

            // Tried all the combination with/without/different order with no change
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Value));
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Text));
        }
    }
}

public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Code { get; }
    public string Label { get; }

    public ComboBoxItem(string code, string label)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Label = label;
    }   
}
```

The `Choices` collection is initialized with some pair: `Code,Label`. I want to display the `Label` to the user and use the `Code` in my business layer. I also want my user to input its own code in the ComboBox (this is why the `IsEditable` dependency property is set to `True` and why I also bind `Text` on my ViewModel).

Everythings works fine when directly bind my ViewModel on the Control. The `_selectedCode` is updated prioritary with the selected `Choices` element or with the manual input  if necessary.

My problem occurs when I pre-set the `_selectedCode` using the SetCode method. The Value property is no longer updated when I chose a new existing `Choice` in the ComboBox...

Is it possible to bind both `SelectedItem` and `Text` of a ComboBox? Do you have an idea why the bound properties are not updated after a programmatic initialization? It is like the event is not fired anymore...

Comment: Your view model may have a `SelectedCode` property. Then set `SelectedValuePath="Code"` and bind `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCode}"` instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: I already tried something like that earlier during my tests. I will give it a new try tomorow and let you know! Thanks

Comment: @Clemens If I only use the `SelectedValue` dependency property (so I don't have the `Text` property bound), the `Value` property in my view model is not set when the user inputs a custom value. If I use both `SelectedValue` and `Text` dependency properties, it is the opposite, the `Text` property in my view model is not updated if I pre-set the value of my view model using the `SetCode` method ...